# How to make array or dictionary from string response in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, string

I am calling php webservice for ios app. I am getting the response as string as follows ;

> a:10:{s:11:"sso_user_id”;s:6:”123456”;s:9:”firstname”;s:3:”xyz”;s:8:”lastname”;s:3:”abc”;s:5:”abono”;s:1:”1”;s:4:”hash";s:32:"638550add0b538a5a771d";s:5:"token";s:32:"78451add0b51245789555514585";s:5:"login";s:8:"xxxxxxxx";s:6:"cookie";s:0:"";s:6:"access";a:5:{s:4:"role";s:6:"TESTER”;s:13:"initial_reads";s:1:"8";s:14:"reads_remained";s:1:"8";s:11:"valid_until";s:9:"2014-11-1";s:10:"tmp_portal";s:10:"google.com";}s:5:"error";s:0:"";}

**...keys.........and........... values**

```
sso_user_id     123456
firstname       xyz
lastname        abc
abono           1
hash            638550add0b538a5a771d
token           78451add0b51245789555514585
login           xxxxx
role            TESTER  
initial_reads   11
valid_until     2014-11-1
tmp_portal      google.com
```

**Note : Where a:10 indicates array of 10 objects and s:11 means string with length of 10 chars.**

But i dont have any idea how to convert this string into array or dictionary to fetch key-values.

Thanks,

Comment: why do you using string as response, use the JSON to achieve easily.

Comment: @KumarKL but i am not getting response in JSON format. And API is made by third party. so i can not tell them to change to JSON response

Comment: I can see one possibility that, search for `" "` and consider the string value as key and value. Do some workaround like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved my problem by following. I am posting my code here so that any other can solve same problem like mine ;

**//in ParsedData.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ParsedData : NSObject
{

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *parsedDataArr;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableDictionary *finalDict;

@end
```

**//in ParsedData.m**

```
#import "ParsedData.h"

@implementation ParsedData

@synthesize parsedDataArr;

-(id)init
{
    parsedDataArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"sso_user_id",@"firstname", @"lastname",@"abono",@"hash",@"token",@"login",@"cookie",@"role",@"initial_reads",@"reads_remained",@"valid_until",@"tmp_portal",@"error",nil];

    return self;
}
```

**// in your ViewVontrller.m ..**

**#imprort "ParsedData.h"**

```
-(void)buildDataFromString:(NSString*)stringToBuild;
{
    ParsedData *pd = [[ParsedData alloc]init];

    pd.finalDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 

    for (int i =0; i < pd.parsedDataArr.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *arrKey = [pd.parsedDataArr objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([stringToBuild rangeOfString:arrKey].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            int length = 0;

            NSString *subString = [stringToBuild substringFromIndex:[stringToBuild rangeOfString:arrKey].location + arrKey.length + 2];

            if ([arrKey isEqualToString:@"initial_reads"] || [arrKey isEqualToString:@"reads_remained"])
            {
                length = [self getIntLengthValue:subString];

                [pd.finalDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:length] forKey:arrKey];

            }
            else
            {
                length = [self getStringLengthValue:subString];

                if (length == 0)
                {
                    [pd.finalDict setValue:@"" forKey:arrKey];
                }

                else
                {
                    // Gets the string inside the first set of parentheses in the regex
                    NSString *inside = [self getKeyValue:subString];

                    [pd.finalDict setValue:inside forKey:arrKey];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"final parsed values dict - %@",pd.finalDict);
}

-(int)getIntLengthValue:(NSString *)subString
{
    NSRegularExpression *regex1 = [NSRegularExpression
                                   regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\"(.+?)\"" options:0 error:NULL];

    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex1 firstMatchInString:subString
                                                      options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subString length] )];

    NSString *str =[subString substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];

    NSCharacterSet *alphaNums = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet *inStringSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:str];
    BOOL isDigitOnly = [alphaNums isSupersetOfSet:inStringSet];

    if (isDigitOnly)
    {
        return [str intValue];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

-(int)getStringLengthValue:(NSString *)subString
{
    NSRegularExpression *regex1 = [NSRegularExpression
                                   regularExpressionWithPattern:@":(.+?):" options:0 error:NULL];

    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex1 firstMatchInString:subString
                                                      options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subString length] )];

    NSString *str =[subString substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];

    int length = [str intValue];

    return length;
}

-(NSString *)getKeyValue:(NSString *)subString
{
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\"(.+?)\"" options:0 error:NULL];

    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:subString
                                                     options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subString length] )];

    // Gets the string inside the first set of parentheses in the regex
    NSString *inside = [subString substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];

    return inside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.It is very easy to get this.If you follow the below coding

```
  //just give your URL instead of my URL

  NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?query=London&num_of_results=3&format=json&key=xkq544hkar4m69qujdgujn7w"]];

  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

  [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

  NSError *err;

  NSURLResponse *response;

  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 //You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.    

 //After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

  NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

  NSArray *array=[[jsonArray objectForKey:@"s"]objectForKey:@"sso_user_id "]objectForKey:@"firstname"]objectForKey:@"lastname"]objectForKey:@"abono"]objectForKey:@"hash"]objectForKey:@"token"]objectForKey:@"login"]objectForKey:@"role "]objectForKey:@"initial_reads"]objectForKey:@"valid_until"]objectForKey:@"tmp_portal"]; // Now i give your  key all keys.So check it.
```

Comment: instead objectForKey also you can give valueForKey for fetching values.

Comment: i am not getting response in JSON format and i am using WSDL webservice i.e by xml parsing

Comment: k.I will help you now.

Answer (score 0):

In your .h part

1. //Step 1 : Add the Delegate classes

   ```
      First of all you should add <NSXMLParserDelegate>
   ```
2. //Step 2 : Create necessary objects

   ```
      NSXMLParser *parser;
      NSMutableData *ReceviedData;
      NSMutableString *currentStringValue;

      NSMutableArray *sso_user_id;
      NSMutableArray *firstName;
      NSMutableArray *lastName;
      NSMutableArray *abono; 
      NSMutableArray *hash; 
      NSMutableArray *token;
      NSMutableArray *login; 
      NSMutableArray *role;
      NSMutableArray *initial_reads;
      NSMutableArray *valid_until;
      NSMutableArray *tmp_portal;
   ```

   In your .m part

   ```
   //Step 3 - Allocate your all  Arrays in your viewDidLoad method

     sso_user_id = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     ....
     tmp_portal = [NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 

   //Step 4 - Create Connection in your viewDidLoad Like 

     [self createConnection:@"http://www.google.com"];//give yoyur valid url.

   - (void)createConnection:(NSString *)urlString
   {
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

      //Step 5 - parser delegate methods are using NSURLConnectionDelegate class or not.
      BOOL success;
      if (!parser)
      {
        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        parser.delegate = self;
        parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = YES;
        success = [parser parse];
        NSLog(@"Success : %c",success);
       }
    }
   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
   {
     NSLog(@"Current Element Name : %@",elementName);

     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"sso_user_id"])
     {
       NSLog(@"The sso_user_id is==%@",elementName);
     }
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstName"])
     {
        NSLog(@"The firstname is==%@",elementName);
     }
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastName"])
     {
        NSLog(@"The lastname is==%@",elementName);
     }
   }
   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
   {
      currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
      NSLog(@"Current String Value : %@",currentStringValue);
   }
   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   {
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"sso_user_id"])
     {
      [sso_user_id addObject:currentStringValue];
     }
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstName"])
     {
      [firstName addObject:currentStringValue];
     }
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastName"])
     {
       [lastName addObject:currentStringValue];
     }
     currentStringValue = nil;
   }
   ```

Comment: i am not getting response like this way. I am getting whole response in string in the method **-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string** instead elements by elements

Comment: You should follow this way.Otherwise it is hard to get response rohan.

Comment: If you want to string ,use string instead of array.Get the values in string.

Comment: Rohan once you get the values,tell me.